# Merging two SQL queries

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Hi everyone I'm trying to merge two queries:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name,$price 
FROM room 
JOIN room_booking ON room.room_id=room_booking.room_id 
WHERE date_booked<>'$us_date' AND capacity>=$partySize
```

and

```
SELECT DISTINCT room_id
FROM room_booking
WHERE room_id NOT IN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT room_id
     FROM room_booking
     WHERE date_booked = '$date'
    )
```

What would be the best way of merging the above so that the final query checks for a date that does not exist in the room_booking table and extracts the relevant information from the room table given it exceeds a given capacity.

Comment: **What** database system, and which version?? **SQL** is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by many database systems - SQL is **NOT** a database product... stuff like this is very often vendor-specific - so we really need to know what database system you're using....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do the job described in text (but i'm not sure what `date_booked<>'$us_date'` is supposed to do):

```
select name, price
from room
where capacity >= $partySize
and room_id not in 
  (select room_id
   from room_booking
   where date_booked = '$date'
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to merge with following way:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name,$price 
FROM room JOIN room_booking ON room.room_id=room_booking.room_id 
WHERE date_booked<>'$us_date' AND capacity>=$partySize AND room_booking.room_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT room_id
                                                                                    FROM room_booking
                                                                                    WHERE room_id NOT IN 
                                                                                        (SELECT DISTINCT room_id
                                                                                         FROM room_booking
                                                                                         WHERE date_booked = '$date'
                                                                                    ));
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe

```
SELECT DISTINCT name,$price 
FROM room 
JOIN room_booking ON room.room_id=room_booking.room_id 
WHERE date_booked<>'$us_date' AND capacity>=$partySize 
AND date_booked <> '$date'
```

?

Or are you looking to list all room_id's too? Just add room_id to the select list then. You can drop the distinct in that case, as I assume room_id's are unique