# how to merge two sql queries with PHP

Tags: php

Is it possible to create 2 "mysql_query" and merge them together before I'm using:
mysql_fetch_array
?

```
$mainQuery_one = mysql_query("SELECT....");
$mainQuery_two = mysql_query("SELECT....");
```

Comment: Try to use http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html

Comment: CHeck quertion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38304475/adding-to-the-same-array-with-two-different-foreach-loops-php-sql/38304645#38304645

Comment: show your sql query.

Comment: You can use UNION ALL to merge two queries

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24934471/merge-two-sql-queries                         http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38258576/how-to-merge-two-sql-select                  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9757824/merging-two-sql-queries

Comment: Thank you for the alternative solutions, but this is not what I asked for...

Comment: Further to @rad11 's comment : If the two queries are `UNION` compatible then you don't need PHP to do this. If they are not `UNION` compatible, then I don't see how merging the queries would be meaningful.

Comment: Could you show samples of the arrays you're getting now and then the array you'd like to end up with based on those samples?

Comment: What is returned by mysql_query("SELECT 42;") - I have no idea, if these are special classes, or whatever. If it is just filtered SQL "text" the above comments already hint you at UNION (SQL level) or rethinking, what a MERGE should look like in easy cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`multi_query`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) function which for this exact requirement. The manual has all the relevant explanation with the sample snippet for your understanding.

To summarize, concatenate the two query string in a single variable and call the function with this variable as a parameter.